# How to login with a socket

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sockets

I have a site lets call it **phones.names.xol.com**.
Using the website I have the problem to login

> There I have create a **database** with a name **backe**.The password
> is **1234**. (It is ok to share the password ). On that database(backe) I have a table name
> it **users**. My socket is **'home/tiger/mysql/run/mysql.sock'.**

Using localhost - all works fine

> I have create on **localhost** , a database name backe with a table name users.The user is root ,password empty.I can login in that page with not a problem.

This is the connection.php.It is located inside a file named b,so b/connection.php

```
 <?php
    
    
    $host='phones.names.xol.com';
    $db = 'backe';
    
    
    $user='root';
    $pass='1234';
    
    
    
    if(gethostname()=='phones.names.xol.com') {
        $mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db,null,'home/tiger/mysql/run/mysql.sock');
    } else {
            $mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db);
    }
    
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . 
        $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
    }


// Check connection
    if (!$mysqli) {
      die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }{
    echo "Connected successfully to database";
    }
    
    
    
    
    
    
    function check_login($mysqli)

{

if(isset($_SESSION['user_id']))
{

$id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$query = "select * from users where user_id = '$id' limit 1";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query);

if($result && mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
$user_data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
return $user_data;



}


} 
}
function random_num($length){
    $text = " ";
    if($length < 5 ){
        $length = 5;
    }
    $len = rand(4,$length);
    for ($i=0; $i < $len; $i++){
        $text .= rand(0,9);
        
}
return $text;
}
    
    ?>
```

In the login.php .I give the basic parts of codes I have

```
<?php





session_start();
include("b/connection.php");

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
{
    
    //something was posted
    $user_name = $_POST['user_name'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    if(!empty($user_name) && !empty($password) && !is_numeric($user_name))
    {
        
    $user_id = random_num(20);  
        $query = "insert into users ( user_id,user_name,password) values ('$user_id','$user_name','$password')";
    
    mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
    header("Location: index.html");
    die;
    }
    else{
        echo "Please enter some valid information!";
    }
    
}






?>
```

> and this is the form of that code as

```
<form method="post" >
Username: <input type="text" name="user_name"/>
<br/>
Password: <input type="password" name="password" />
<br/>
<input type="submit" value="Login"/><br><br>


</form>
```

How can I make it work on a link ( lets say https:\www.phones.names.xol.com) as it works on localhost?I have been trying for hours to do it but I didn't managed to.The database are good the problem is I think in b/connection.php.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](https://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Exactly what errors are you getting when you try it on the hosted environment?

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing an access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Any modern [development framework](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with an [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text** or a weak hash like **SHA1 or MD5**.

Comment: `$host` is usually just `'localhost'`. Of course, you should use prepared statements.

Comment: Creating random numbers for your `user_id` seems like a bad plan. Why not use an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column?

Comment: @tadman yes indeed .but anyway that's not the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're connecting to a local socket:

```php
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', $user, $pass, $db, null, '/home/tiger/mysql/run/mysql.sock');
```

I'm presuming that this is meant to convey `/host`, not a relative path like `host`.

Comment: hello , should I replace your answer with this  $mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db,null,'home/tiger/mysql/run/mysql.sock');?

Comment: `$host` is part of the problem here. It needs to be `'localhost'`. The domain of the site is completely irrelevant if you're using a *local* socket.

Comment: You should also check that path. I'm almost certain that should be `/home/...` unless for some bizarre reason you have a literal `home` path relative to your web root.

Comment: It show me error line 22 :this is the line with the socket $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', $user, $pass, $db,null,

Comment: What error, specifically? Please include the full text.

Comment: line 34 :$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', $user, $pass,$db);
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . 
    $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}

Comment: the error is :(HY000/2002): No such file or directory and all  the path it has

Comment: If you need to connect by the socket you *must* include the socket path. That line does not.

Comment: Again, please confirm the path. I'm almost certain it's `/home/...` not `home/...`

Comment: yes it is /home and not home... on line 22 I have this error message : mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: $user='root';
$pass='';
$host='localhost';
$db = 'backe';   this is the way I define those

Comment: ➟ ➡︎ **Please confirm the path to the socket**.

Comment: ' /home/tiger/mysql/run/mysql.sock ' it is like this..

Comment: Alright, now be sure to use that in your `new` call. That code you show did not use it correctly.

Comment: I was using that /home/tiger/mysql/run/mysql.sock and I was getting those errors

Comment: If it's saying path not found then that might be wrong, you need to confirm it and possibly adjust it based on information only you can find. I can't help any further. Normally this involves logging into the machine in question and using tools like `ls` or `find` to identify where that socket is.

Comment: Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) you mean that this means that my socket is wrong?

Comment: guys it worked I delete it the lines I had problem ,your answer is working fine .Thanks a lot of your help